# Controls on .ascx are null in .ascx.cs

Tags: asp.net

I am creating a custom web control but the controls I have on the .ascx file are null when I reference it in .cs file. Am I missing something?

.ASCX

```
<asp:Table runat="server" BorderWidth="0" BorderStyle="None">
<asp:TableRow VerticalAlign="Middle" BorderWidth="0">
    <asp:TableCell HorizontalAlign="Center" BorderWidth="0" BorderStyle="None">
        <asp:Button ID="button" runat="server" Text="Button" />
    </asp:TableCell>
</asp:TableRow>

<asp:TableFooterRow BorderWidth="0" BorderStyle="None">
    <asp:TableCell HorizontalAlign="Center" ID="caption" Font-Size="12pt" Height="80px" VerticalAlign="Top" BorderWidth="0" BorderStyle="None" BorderColor="Transparent" />
</asp:TableFooterRow>
</asp:Table>
```

.ASCX.CS

```
public void Process()
{
    button.Text = "ok"; //it fails here because it's null;
}
```

Test.aspx

```
MyButton button = new MyButton();
button.Process();
```

Comment: Call `LoadControl()`, rather than instantiating the item.

Comment: My requirement is that I need to create all the controls dynamically based on instructions from database.
I tried these but both fails with 'Object reference is null'
MyButton button = Page.LoadControl(typeof(MyButton),null) as MyButton;
MyButton button = Page.LoadControl("MyButton.ascx") as MyButton;

Answer (score 0):

The controls can be null if:

1. Is inside a `PlaceHolder` and you change the controls by delete it programmatically
2. Is on cache, and the asp.net use the cached rendered data and not create it again
3. Is inside a `ContentPlaceHolder` and you change that content with some other
4. In general speaking the controls can be added, remove and delete on run time.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you wanted to add dynamic controls from code behind, you must have to add that control in any of your aspx or ascx html control.

The code should be like this. :

```
Button btnNew = new MyButton();
btnNew.Process();
btnNew.Controls.Add(pnlTest);
```

where "pnlTest" should be your any html control defined in ascx page.

**Update**

Here is the updated answer of your post

```
Button btnNew = new Button();

btnNew.Click += new EventHandler(btnNew_Click);    
btnNew.ID = "btnNew";
void btnNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Process();
}
btnNew.Controls.Add(pnlTest);
```

It will work for you.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing, but it fails even before I add it to the panel. It fails at btnNew.Process();